# Keep code DRY on create/edit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few inputs that are used in my form for both create and update. I decided to make them a component.

```
// used for CRU on the event record
import React from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slds-form">
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.assigned = input} type="text" className="slds-input" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Related To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.related = input} type="text" className="slds-input" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Location</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.location = input} type="text" className="slds-input" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event Start</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.start = input} type="text" className="slds-input" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event End</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.end = input} type="text" className="slds-input" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Contact</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.contact = input} type="text" className="slds-input" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="slds-button slds-button--brand">{this.props.buttonLabel}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

I then attempted to use this component in my `<Create />` component.

```
// used for Create on the event record
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';

class Create extends React.Component {

  createEvent(e) {
    console.log("createEvent() has fired.");
    e.preventDefault();
    const event = {
      assigned: this.assigned.value,
      related: this.related.value,
      location: this.location.value,
      start: this.start.value,
      end: this.end.value,
      contact: this.contact.value
    }
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={(e) => this.createEvent(e)}>
        <Form buttonLabel="Create" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Create;
```

When I try to hit the Create button on my `<Create />` component I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Create.createEvent (webpack:///./src/components/Event/Create.js?:42:32)
    at onSubmit (webpack:///./src/components/Event/Create.js?:59:27)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js?:70:16)
    at executeDispatch (webpack:///./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:89:21)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (webpack:///./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:112:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (webpack:///./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:44:22)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (webpack:///./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:55:10)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (webpack:///./~/react/lib/forEachAccumulated.js?:25:9)
    at Object.processEventQueue (webpack:///./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:231:7)
```

I then check the console and see the `refs` belong in my `<Form />` component, and not my `<Create />` component.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to pass the refs from my child component, `<Form />`, to its parent, `<Create />`?

Comment: You could pass a method down (from parent to child) that takes in a variable (object would be optimal) then use that in the parent somehow.

Comment: @A.Lau I didn't know you could do that. Could you share a link of were that is done?

Comment: I learnt my react by watching youtube videos, specifically LearnCode.academy. Might want to check them out. They passed a method to the child in one of those videos I think. So what happens is your pass the parent method down to the child, the child then calls the props method which then gets used by the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of `refs`! Good news, you really don't need them, at all. As a very very general rule, you should only be using refs if you are interacting with an external library that doesn't "understand" React (d3, Greensock, TinyMCE, etc).

Tackling it in an [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) way can be done like:

```
const User = (props) => (
  <div>
    <input name="foo" className="form-control" />
    <input name="foo2" className="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">{props.buttonLabel}</button>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <br />
        <form onChange={this.onChange} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <User buttonLabel="Create"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Codepen example:
http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/zNXxga?editors=0010

Comment: how would this works if you are using props in the `const User`? I'm getting an error of "is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."

Comment: would that mean it needs its own state?